# Submit whole form when select option is changed without reload page

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I need to submit the whole form when I change a select option and save it to mysql without reload page.

I have this code, but only POST the select option value and I need to POST the hidden values in the form too.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action='#' name="dateForm">
  <input type='hidden' name='cond_acao' class='form-control' value="edit_seccao_formando">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_formando" value="<?=$linha_formandos[id_formando];?>">
  <select name="id_seccoes" class="form-control" onchange="return postSelection">
       <option selected="selected" value="1">car</option>
       <option value="2">boat</option>
       <option value="3">plane</option>     
    </select>
  <div id='response_seccoes'></div>
  <script>
    function postSelection(selectObject) {
      var id_seccoes = window.dateForm.id_seccoes.value = selectObject.options[selectObject.selectedIndex].value;
      var dataString = "id_seccoes=" + id_seccoes;
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "url.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response) {
$('#response_seccoes').html("ok").fadeIn(100).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
          //$("#list").html(response);
        }
      });
      return false;
    };
  </script>
</form>
```

It's possible to serialize instead of especified the strings?

Can anyone help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are using Jquery, I suggest you monitor the select button for change using a jquery function like

```
$("id_seccoes").change(function(){
    //call your post method here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand what I need to change to do what you are propose.

Comment: I am assuming you need to post some data to the server when you change any of your select dropdown. In this case you can write above code in you script file and then 
$("id_seccoes").change(function(){
   myMethodToPostData(myData);
});

Comment: What you say is like that:
<script>
$("id_seccoes").change(function(){
$.ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url: "url.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
        success: function (response) {

            $('#response_seccoes').html("ok").fadeIn(100).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
            //$("#list").html(response);


        }
});
</script>

Comment: yes that is right however I suggest you make a separate file for your scripts, and import that in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action='#' name="dateForm">
<input type='hidden' name='cond_acao' class='form-control' value="edit_seccao_formando">
<input type="hidden" name="id_formando" value="<?=$linha_formandos[id_formando];?>">                           
<select name="id_seccoes" class="form-control">
<option value="1">car</option>
<option value="2">boat</option>
 <option value="3">plane</option>      
</select>
</form> 
<div id='response_seccoes'></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name="id_seccoes"]').change(function(){
        $.post('url.php',$('[name="dateForm"]').serialize(),function(response){
            $('#response_seccoes').html("ok").fadeIn(100).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is better to explain how your code solves the problem than pasting a code dump

Comment: It's working fine. Let me know what error we have got with this code.